# what would cause go to spend so much time in runtime.pthread_cond_signal

Tags: go, channel, pprof

I have written a multi-goroutine benchmark test in go. And I use the go tool pprof to analyze how to optimize my code. When I use top10 to show some information, I got the following outputs:

```
Showing top 10 nodes out of 167
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
    4700ms 17.86% 17.86%     4700ms 17.86%  runtime.pthread_cond_signal
    1790ms  6.80% 24.66%     1790ms  6.80%  cmpbody
    1470ms  5.59% 30.24%     1620ms  6.16%  syscall.syscall
    1360ms  5.17% 35.41%     3280ms 12.46%  runtime.scanobject
    1170ms  4.45% 39.86%     1410ms  5.36%  runtime.findObject
     960ms  3.65% 43.50%      960ms  3.65%  runtime.pthread_cond_wait
     950ms  3.61% 47.11%      950ms  3.61%  runtime.memmove
     650ms  2.47% 49.58%      650ms  2.47%  runtime.usleep
     650ms  2.47% 52.05%     2490ms  9.46%  talent.TopN.func1
     630ms  2.39% 54.45%     2890ms 10.98%  runtime.mallocgc
```

It's obviously that the runtime.pthread_cond_signal spend so much time in my code. I try to google to search some usable information about runtime.pthread_cond_signal. But failed to got them. Though Some posts have mentioned it, they just provide few tips, and keep me still confused about it.

I guess that this situation is relative about the channel's usage in Go, but I am not sure about my opinion, and I also don't know some details about that.

What I want to know is the following:

1. What would cause go to spend so much time in runtime.pthread_cond_signal usually?
2. In normal conditions，how to optimize your go code when this situation happens？

Feel free to provide any information and advice.
I would appreciate to receive any help from you.

Comment: From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/99ijxe/go_pprof_assistance/)

1. are you doing a LOT of channel sends and receives ? Perhaps the amount of work you are doing vs the amount you are handing off between goroutines is relatively small
2. are you generating a lot of garbage ? I recommend running your program with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 and looking at the frequency of the gc trace output, if it is continuous, that could be a sign you are generating too much garbage.

Comment: try `web` command in pprof console: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Answer (score 4):

This likely means your code is doing a lot of locking/unlocking. `pthread_cond_signal` is used to notify condition variables, and is only used by Go on OSX, it seems. It's used in the implementation of `semawakeup` which itself is used in the `unlock` primitive, which is used everywhere locking/unlocking is done.

As the comments suggested, try the `(web)` command in `go tool pprof` to see where these calls are made from.

It's hard to provide more details without seeing your specific benchmark.